# How to get lines from two char arrays to check the equality between each of their lines

Tags: c, char, string-comparison, c-strings, strcmp

I'm programming for a uni project. Currently, I have a function for my consumer thread but the issue isn't there now. The issue is that instead of checking the equality of the content(arg->lineF1 and arg->lineF2), I'd like to loop through each of their lines(given that arg->lineF1 and arg->lineF2 are char array) and to check for each of their lines the equality, I've tried some things but they haven't work so far.

I have to specify that the solutions I found to these problems were not working(tried strtok failed, tried looping but I was not getting empty lines).

```
void * fonctionConsummer(void * args){
    struct argumentThreadConsummer *arg = (struct argumentThreadConsummer *)args;


    //-----------------LINE BY LINE CHECKING------------------------------------
    void * fonctionConsummer(void * args){
    struct argumentThreadConsummer *arg = (struct argumentThreadConsummer *)args;


    //-----------------LINE BY LINE CHECKING------------------------------------
    int counter = 0;
    const char s[2] = "\n";
    char *lineF1;
    char *lineF2;
    lineF1 = strtok(arg->lineF1,s);
    lineF2 = strtok(arg->lineF2,s);
    while(lineF1 != NULL || lineF2 != NULL){
        printf("%d ", counter);
        printf("Line F1 %s\n" , lineF1); // Add the new line character here since it is removed from the lineF1ization process
        printf("Line F2 %s\n" , lineF2); // Add the new line character here since it is removed from the lineF1ization process
        counter++;
        lineF1 = strtok(NULL, s);
        lineF2 = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if(strcmp (arg->lineF1, arg->lineF2) == 0){
        printf("\nLes fichiers ont le meme contenu\n");
        pthread_exit(0);
    }
    printf("\nLes fichiers n'ont pas le meme contenu\n");
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Content of the two files :

[image: content of my two files]

the output is :

[image]

I don't understand why I'm getting null from F2(in the second iteration)

Thanks in advance for the help, I'm a beginner in C programming.

Comment: What have you tried with `strtok()` which did not work? That's exactly the solution to your problem. Show that code.

Comment: The error might also come from how you read the files. Please show a [mcve]. Your code is incomplete, cut it down to the minimum possible to reproduce the problem you're facing (e.g. you probably don't even need threads to reproduce the problem).

Comment: suggest removing the lines: `//-----------------LINE BY LINE CHECKING------------------------------------
    void * fonctionConsummer(void * args){
    struct argumentThreadConsummer *arg = (struct argumentThreadConsummer *)args;`

Comment: regarding: `if(strcmp (arg->lineF1, arg->lineF2) == 0){`  Since the call(s) to `strtok()` replaced an '\n' with a NUL byte and `strcmp()` stops at the first NUL byte encountered, the result is ONLY the very first part of each line will be compared, rather than the whole of each array

Comment: please do not post images, rather copy/past the actual text

Comment: Note: there are NOT two files.  However, there are two char, NUL terminated arrays

Comment: Since the objective seems to be to compare each char string, delimiting them via '\n',  and since `strtok()` fails to work when two different arrays are involved, The posted code cannot be easily corrected.  Suggest just use `memcmp()` on the whole of each char array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` stores data on the string being parsed in a static location, which means that you can only use it on one string at a time.  If you use it on two strings at the same time (like you're trying to do), the second call will clobber the info from the first call.  You could use `strtok_r` instead, but that would still have an additional problem -- blank lines (two consecutive newlines) would be skipped, so your comparisons would (incorrectly?) return a match if the inputs differ by blank lines.  You can avoid that problem (as well as the reentrancy) by using `strsep` instead:

```
char *lineF1, *saveF1 = arg->lineF1;
char *lineF2, *saveF2 = arg->lineF2;
lineF1 = strsep(&saveF1, s);
lineF2 = strsep(&saveF2, s);
while(lineF1 != NULL || lineF2 != NULL){
    :
    lineF1 = strsep(&saveF1, s);
    lineF2 = strsep(&saveF2, s);
}
```

if your system doen't have strsep (it's a BSD/GNU libc specific function), you can define it yourself as:

```
char *strsep(char **str, const char *delim) {
    char *rv = *str;
    if (rv) {
        *str += strcspn(rv, delim);
        if (**str)
            *(*str)++ = '\0';
        else
            *str = 0; }
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if two files are identical, as i understood from your statement, you can use memory mapped files, here is the reference to some info about it : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html.
What this does it puts the content in your file in memory, and you can access the content of the file as you access a buffer.